# The jquery slider doesnt work on Safari 3.2

Tags: jquery, safari, jquery-ui-slider

I am using jquery 1.8.2 and jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js to create sliders. But somehow the slider isnt working properly on Safari 3.2 but works just fine on Safari 5.1.7

Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic issue here is that safari 3.2 doesnt understand .offset();

So in a way you will have to read the jquery file and change .offset() to offsetLeft;